# Adding new table row and inserting value in database php/mysql/jquery

Tags: php

I am trying to do a trial balance page,when i add new row to input values and hit save  it does not take all the rows in the table instead it saves the first one.

PHP

```
 <tr class="item-row" style="font-size:12px;">
     <td class="item-name" style="margin-right: 5em;background:#A7d6F1;">
          <div class="delete-wpr">
              <textarea onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)" style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;" rows="2" cols="43" maxlength="6"class="code" name="acc_code[]" id="acc_code[]"></textarea>
              <textarea onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)" readonly style="text-align:center;margin-top:-34px;margin-left:20em;font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;" rows="2" cols="10" maxlength="6"class="type" name="type[]" id="type[]"></textarea>
              <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
          </div>
     </td>            
     <td class="item-name" align="center">
          <textarea onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)" autocomplete="off" style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;" rows="2" cols="8" maxlength="6" name="int_code[]" id="int_code[]" class="intCode"></textarea>
     </td>
     <td >
          <textarea onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)" autocomplete="off" style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;"rows="2" cols="15" maxlength="11" name="debit_mvt[]" id="debit_mvt[]" class="cost"></textarea>
     </td>
     <td style="">
          <textarea onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)" autocomplete="off" style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;" rows="2" cols="15" maxlength="11" name="credit_mvt[]" id="credit_mvt[]" class="qty"></textarea>
     </td>
     <td>
          <textarea style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;" rows="2" cols="15" maxlength="10" autocomplete="off" name="balance[]" id="balance[]" class="price" readonly></textarea>
     </td>
     <td style="background:#A7D6F1;font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;">
          <textarea style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;border:none;background-color:white"rows="2" cols="15" maxlength="10" class="deb"name="debitOld[]" id="debitOld[]" ></textarea>
     </td>
     <td style="background:#A7D6F1;font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;">
          <textarea style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;border:none;background-color:white"rows="2" cols="15" maxlength="10" class="cred"name="creditOld[]" id="creditOld[]" ></textarea>
     </td>
```

Add a row

Jquery

```
$("#addrow").click(function(){

$(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row" style="font-size:12px;"><td class="item-name" style="background:#A7d6F1;"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea  style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;" rows="2" cols="43" maxlength="6"colspan="3" class="code" name="acc_code[]" id="acc_code[]"></textarea><textarea onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)" onkeyup="return check_type()"readonly style="text-align:center;margin-top:-34px;margin-left:20em;font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;" rows="2" cols="10" maxlength="6"class="type" name="type[]" id="type[]"></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td ><textarea  style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;" rows="2" cols="8" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off" name="int_Code[]" id="int_Code[]" class="intCode"></textarea></td><td><textarea onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;"rows="2" cols="15" maxlength="10" name="acc_deb[]" id="acc_deb[]" autocomplete="off" class="cost"></textarea></td><td style=""><textarea onkeypress="return tabE(this,event)"style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;" rows="2" cols="15" maxlength="9" autocomplete="off" name="acc_cred[]" id="acc_cred[]" class="qty"></textarea></td><td><textarea style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;" rows="2" cols="15" maxlength="10" name="balance[]" id="balance[]" class="price" readonly></textarea></td><td style="background:#A7D6F1;font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;"><textarea style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;border:none;background-color:white"rows="2" cols="15" maxlength="10" class="deb"name="debitOld[]" id="debitOld[]" ></textarea></td><td style="background:#A7D6F1;font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;"><textarea style="font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;border:none;background-color:white"rows="2" cols="15" maxlength="10" class="cred" name="creditOld[]" id="creditOld[]" ></textarea></td></tr>');
```

PHP code that inserts data into mysql:

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO trialb ( acc_code,type,int_code,debit_mvt,credit_mvt,balance,debitOld,creditOld,date1,date2,comp_name,user_name,year,status,dt1,dt2 )
VALUES";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['acc_code']); $i++) {

$sql .= " ('{$_POST['acc_code'][$i]}', '{$_POST['type'][$i]}', '{$_POST['int_code'][$i]}', '{$_POST['debit_mvt'][$i]}','{$_POST['credit_mvt'][$i]}','{$_POST['balance'][$i]}','{$_POST['debitOld'][$i]}','{$_POST['creditOld'][$i]}','{$_SESSION["date1"]}','{$_SESSION["date2"]}','{$_SESSION["name"]}','{$_SESSION["user_name"]}',Now(),'opened','{$_SESSION["date1"]}','{$_SESSION["date2"]}'),";


}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);
```

Why isn't it inserting all rows???

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is not very readable like this, please use proper indentation.

Second, never EVER insert directly from $_POST (or any other input) without any input validation.

Third, what is the value of `count($_POST['acc_code'])` what is the produced query `$sql`? You need information, you need to debug. Use echo's and print_r's to get the debug data, in case of an AJAX call, try Firebug or use `error_log` to place debug data in you php error log.

Comment: First of all im sorry that my code is not that clear or readable,second of all the count is always 1 as if it's not inserting the rest of the values in the their relevant array.

Comment: i have used the inserting method with another page where values are retrieved from mysql and i have noticed that if rows are present when page is loaded and you change values it insert them without no problem but if the rows you add them after the page is loaded it doesn't see them

Comment: Even after i have added the rows i went to check if i can be able to see them in the source page but they do not show is that normal?

Comment: How exactly do you submit the form, perhaps this is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198055/form-not-submitting-dynamically-generated-inputs-jquery

Comment: <form name="insert" id="insert" action="trial_insert.php"class="insert" method="post">

Comment: As i said before it works fine when the rows are loaded with the page,like if you have 100 rows loaded and you do some changes to the values it would save properly but lets say you need to insert another row and you click on the add row link and you fill the values and click save you expect it to save 101 rows values but that's not the case it save or updates the rows already loaded but the one or ones you add using jquery it doesn't see them

Comment: (sorry was out to lunch)

I've put you're code in a very crude testcase wich I cant post here. Works fine.

Are the new fields inserted in the form?

Comment: It is weird that it is able to see the rows loaded with the page but it is not able to see the ones you add after page load.shouldn't i be able to see the html code of the generated row in the page source?

Comment: of course they are inserted in the form because the form is closed at the en so basically it searches for the last row which is obviously in the form and inserts that row after

Comment: Like I said, in my own test based on your code it works fine. You have not posted complete code so it leaves me guessing ;)

Btw. generated rows are not visible in page source unless you use a tool for that. De developer toolbar for FireFox is great, it has a 'View generated source' option.

Comment: Thanks for your help but im just trying to answer your questions the best way possible and i didn't know i need a tool to view it thanks for the info.

Comment: Is there a way to post the entire page code and so that it is visible?Excuse my ignorance cause its just the second time i post on this site

Comment: I have installed the developer tools for firefox and i noticed that the loaded rows have odd and even added to the class but the ones i add after page load don't have that

Comment: In the debugger section it doesn't see the added row with the values yet it sees the others but under the inspector it shows that it has been added its just weird

Comment: Solved..... i had the submit button at the top of the table all i did is i put it at the bottom and it solved the problem.